# TypeScript types assignation

Tags: typescript, types

Can somebody explain or give link to docs or somehow make me understand this:

```js
interface User {
  id: number
  email: string
}

interface StringedObjectInterface {
  [k: string]: string | number
}

const myObject = {
  id: 42,
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
}

const myUser: User = {
  id: 42,
  email: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
}

fnI(myObject)
fnI(myUser) // << Gives an error

function fnI(value: StringedObjectInterface) {
  return value
}
```

> Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StringedObjectInterface'.
> Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'User'.

Adding index signature in User is not a solver, am I right ?
I don't understand how to solve this in "right" way.

User in literally `2 string fields with string | number`, why it doesn't fit ?

According [this article](https://blog.thoughtspile.tech/2023/01/23/typescript-sets/) `StringedObjectInterface` includes all values that `User` can ever had

Comment: The error is not about the value part. It is for the key part. Your `StringedObjectInterface` requires keys to be the string type but the interface doesn't satisfy. The interfaces won't have string-keyed values unless you say so. You you can either add it to your interface or you can use `satisfies` keyword.

Comment: See if [this](https://tsplay.dev/wEgxZm) works for you.